# Jquery add price total after selections are made

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to click on the checkbox and the total price will change. The prices are per day so if I add days it should calculate that for that row and that total should include that as well.

DEMO **http://jsfiddle.net/XqUH2/3/**

```
<table id="postForm_promote">
  <tr><th>Features</th><th></th><th>Duration</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="ad_promote_highlight" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:top;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ad_promote" value="1" id="ad_promote_highlight">Highlight
        </label>  
    </td>
    <td class="ad_promote_info">What's this?</td>    
    <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" name="ad_promote_days" class="ad_promote_days"> day(s)</td>
    <td>$0.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="ad_promote_mediumsize" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:top;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ad_promote" value="2" id="ad_promote_mediumsize">Medium Size
        </label>  
    </td>
    <td class="ad_promote_info">What's this?</td> 
    <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" name="ad_promote_days" class="ad_promote_days"> day(s)</td>
    <td>$0.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="ad_promote_largesize" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:top;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ad_promote" value="3" id="ad_promote_largesize">Large Size
        </label>  
    </td>
    <td class="ad_promote_info">What's this?</td> 
    <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" name="ad_promote_days" class="ad_promote_days"> day(s)</td>
    <td>$1.49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <label for="ad_promote_frontpage" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align:top;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ad_promote" value="4" id="ad_promote_frontpage">Front Page
        </label>  
    </td>
    <td class="ad_promote_info">What's this?</td> 
    <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" name="ad_promote_days" class="ad_promote_days"> day(s)</td>
    <td>$2.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td id="ad_promote_total_border"><div id="ad_promote_total_cost">$0.00</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I am not good at jquery so I was not sure how to achieve this. I know it has something to do with .change(...) and variables math but not sure how to set up the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="number"]').change(function(){

  var priceRow = $(this).parent().next();

  priceRow.text('$'+Math.round($(this).val()*priceRow.attr('unit-price')*100)/100);

  updateTotal();
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

  updateTotal();

});

function updateTotal(){

  var total = 0;

  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){

       var priceRow = $(this).parents('tr').children('td[unit-price]');

       total += parseFloat(priceRow.text().replace('$',''))

  })


  $('#ad_promote_total_cost').text('$'+total);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XqUH2/7/

Comment: Hey how can I remove the disabled attribute for the checkbox that is selected? http://jsfiddle.net/XqUH2/8/